# XML to CSV : a native way to create flat files?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, csv

There is a lot of questions about XML to CSV conversion but mine is quite precise so I ask it here.

I threat inventories and get XML files like :

```
<item>
   <sku>abc</sku>
   <title>un livre</title>
   <price>42</price>
   <attributes>
      <attribute>
          <name>Nombre de pages</name>
          <value>123</value>
      </attribute>
      <attribute>
          <name>Auteur</name>
          <value>bob la mouche</value>
      </attribute>
   </attributes>
   <contributors>
      <contributor>toto</contributor>
      <contributor>titi</contributor>
      <contributor>tata</contributor>
   </contributors>
</item>
```

I need to convert it to a 2D format. I would like to use a quite known format like array/object disposition, columns would look like :

```
sku
title
price
attributes.attribute[0].name
attributes.attribute[0].value
attributes.attribute[1].name
attributes.attribute[1].value
contributors.contributor[0]
contributors.contributor[1]
contributors.contributor[2]
```

If there is no direct answer, do not code it for me, I know how to make it and will be pleased to share it to you. But that's just to know if there is a direct way (such as using very exotic XML methods existing somewhere on a xml parsing lib).

Thanks

Comment: Did it work for you or do you need a more detailed answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I wrote I already know how to do it by hand. I'm looking for something less manual, if it exists. Else I'll develop a converter myself, tomorrow I think.

Comment: Well, it's not too much left to do. Inserting ten lines of xpath, one for each element to fetch, and you're good to go. Definitely faster than any other approach on this task I suppose.

Comment: This piece of XML is a sample, it could be any XML, so there's more than ten lines left to go, but your approach is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not found any efficient way to do this. [RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) was a good candidate but unfortunately, it only gives a single-value as key and not the full path to the final node.

I finally developed a class that does this exact thing : it takes any XML document and creates a CSV with a "array/object" disposition.

```
/**
 * This class converts a multidimentional XML file into a CSV file.
 * First XML level are distinct CSV lines
 * Last XML level are values
 * Path from the first to the last XML levels are CSV column names.
 *
 * @todo May be conflicts with XML nodes with names finishing by [n].
 *              => Case <x>test</x><x>test</x><x[0]>test</x[0]>
 *                 will generate 2 times x[0] on CSV file.
 *
 * @author ninsuo <ninsuo at gmail dot com>
 */
class Xml2Csv
{

    /**
     * An array that looks like :
     *
     * array(
     *   'simple.name' => stdClass(
     *      ->names => array('real.name[0]', 'real.name[1]', ...)
     *      ->positions => array('position-in-rows-1', 'position-in-rows-2', ...)
     *   ),
     *   ...
     * )
     *
     * Allow us to create dynamic column names according to
     * content disposition.
     *
     * @access private
     * @var array
     */
    private $columnNames;

    /**
     * Rows of CSV file
     *
     * @access private
     * @var array
     */
    private $rows;

    /**
     * Current row number
     *
     * @access private
     * @var int
     */
    private $rowNumber;

    public function convert($xmlSource, $csvTarget)
    {
        $this->_checkSourceAndTarget($xmlSource, $csvTarget);

        libxml_use_internal_errors();
        try
        {
            $tree = new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlSource, 0, true);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't load XML : " . $e->getMessage());
        }
        libxml_clear_errors();

        $this->_reset();

        $this->_browseXMLTree($tree);
        unset($tree);

        $this->_writeCSV($csvTarget);

        $this->_reset();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if $source file exists and is readable.
     * Checks if $target file is writable
     *
     * @access private
     * @param string $source
     * @param string $target
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function _checkSourceAndTarget($source, $target)
    {
        if ((!is_file($source)) || (!is_readable($source)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Source file does not exist or is not readable.");
        }
        if (((is_file($target)) && (!is_writable($target))) || (!is_writable(dirname($target))))
        {
            throw new Exception("Target file is not writable.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reset attributes (avoid taking huge amount of memory when converting big files)
     *
     * @access private
     */
    private function _reset()
    {
        $this->columnNames = array ();
        $this->rows = array ();
        $this->rowNumber = 0;
    }

    /**
     * First XML-level are CSV rows
     *
     * @access private
     * @param SimpleXMLIterator $tree
     */
    private function _browseXMLTree($tree)
    {
        foreach ($tree as $node)
        {
            if (count($node) > 0)
            {
                $this->rows[$this->rowNumber] = array ();
                $this->_browseXMLNode($node);
                $this->rowNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Browsing next XML levels until a node has no child (CSV value)
     *
     * @access private
     * @param type $node
     * @param array $path
     */
    private function _browseXMLNode($node, array &$path = array ())
    {
        array_push($path, $node->getName());
        foreach ($node as $key => $child)
        {
            if (count($child) > 0)
            {
                $this->_browseXMLNode($child, $path);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_addValue(implode('.', $path) . '.' . $key, strval($child));
            }
        }
        array_pop($path);
    }

    /**
     * Create a CSV column if it does not exist.
     * Add a value to the given CSV column.
     *
     * @access private
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $value
     */
    private function _addValue($column, $value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($column, $this->columnNames))
        {
            $columnInfo = $this->columnNames[$column];
            foreach ($columnInfo->positions as $position)
            {
                if (array_key_exists($position, $this->rows[$this->rowNumber]) == false)
                {
                    $this->rows[$this->rowNumber][$position] = $value;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (count($columnInfo->positions) == 1)
            {
                $columnInfo->names[0] .= '[0]';
            }
            $columnPosition = $this->_countCSVColumns();
            array_push($columnInfo->names, $column . '[' . count($columnInfo->positions) . ']');
            array_push($columnInfo->positions, $columnPosition);
            $this->columnNames[$column] = $columnInfo;
            $this->rows[$this->rowNumber][$columnPosition] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $columnPosition = $this->_countCSVColumns();
            $columnInfo = new stdClass();
            $columnInfo->names[0] = $column;
            $columnInfo->positions[0] = $columnPosition;
            $this->columnNames[$column] = $columnInfo;
            $this->rows[$this->rowNumber][$columnPosition] = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return current number of columns in the CSV file.
     * Used to get index of a new column.
     *
     * @access private
     * @return int
     */
    private function _countCSVColumns()
    {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($this->columnNames as $columnInfo)
        {
            $count += count($columnInfo->positions);
        }
        return $count;
    }

    /**
     * Write CSV file
     *
     * @access private
     * @param string $csvTarget
     */
    private function _writeCSV($csvTarget)
    {
        $columns = $this->_getCSVColumns();
        if (($handle = fopen($csvTarget, 'w')) === false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot open target file : fopen() failed.");
        }
        $this->_writeCsvRow($handle, $columns);

        $columnPositions = array_keys($columns);
        $columnNumber = count($columnPositions);
        for ($currentRow = 0; ($currentRow < $this->rowNumber); $currentRow++)
        {
            $csvRow = array ();
            for ($currentColumn = 0; ($currentColumn < $columnNumber); $currentColumn++)
            {
                $position = $columnPositions[$currentColumn];
                if (array_key_exists($position, $this->rows[$currentRow]) == false)
                {
                    $csvRow[$position] = '';
                }
                else
                {
                    $csvRow[$position] = $this->rows[$currentRow][$position];
                }
            }
            $this->_writeCsvRow($handle, $csvRow);
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }

    /**
     * Return CSV columns as a single array
     *
     * @access private
     * @return array
     */
    private function _getCSVColumns()
    {
        $columns = array ();
        foreach ($this->columnNames as $columnInfo)
        {
            foreach ($columnInfo->names as $key => $name)
            {
                $columns[$columnInfo->positions[$key]] = $name;
            }
        }
        ksort($columns);
        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Write a row into CSV file
     *
     * @access private
     * @param resource $handle
     * @param array $csvRow
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function _writeCsvRow($handle, $csvRow)
    {
        if (fputcsv($handle, $csvRow, "\t", '"') === false)
        {
            fclose($handle);
            throw new Exception("Cannot write target file, fputcsv() failed.");
        }
    }

}
```

## Demo :

1/ Create a demo.xml file :

```
<items>
<item>
   <sku>abc 1</sku>
   <title>a book 1</title>
   <price>42 1</price>
   <attributes>
      <attribute>
          <name>Number of pages 1</name>
          <value>123 1</value>
      </attribute>
      <attribute>
          <name>Author 1</name>
          <value>Rob dude 1</value>
      </attribute>
   </attributes>
   <contributors>
      <contributor>John 1</contributor>
      <contributor>Ryan 1</contributor>
   </contributors>
</item>
<item>
   <sku>abc 2</sku>
   <title>a book 2</title>
   <price>42 2</price>
   <attributes>
      <attribute>
          <name>Number of pages 2</name>
          <value>123 2</value>
      </attribute>
      <attribute>
          <name>Author 2</name>
          <value>Rob dude 2</value>
      </attribute>
   </attributes>
   <contributors>
      <contributor>John 2</contributor>
      <contributor>Ryan 2</contributor>
   </contributors>
</item>
</items>
```

2/ Put this somewhere in your work

```
$service = new Xml2Csv();
$service->convert('demo.xml', 'demo.csv');
```

3/ Check the "demo.csv" output:

```
item.sku    item.title  item.price  item.attributes.attribute.name[0]   item.attributes.attribute.value[0]  item.attributes.attribute.name[1]   item.attributes.attribute.value[1]  item.contributors.contributor[0]    item.contributors.contributor[1]
"abc 1" "a book 1"  "42 1"  "Number of pages 1" "123 1" "Author 1"  "Rob dude 1"    "John 1"    "Ryan 1"
"abc 2" "a book 2"  "42 2"  "Number of pages 2" "123 2" "Author 2"  "Rob dude 2"    "John 2"    "Ryan 2"
```

Note : this is quickly written but you can of course change the CSV separator or whatever you want by adding some parameters to `convert()` method.

Enjoy.

Comment: I'm everytime shocked anew, to see how much code you need for this kind of stuff in java.

Comment: php actually. if you know a better way i would love to learn.

Comment: Without the urge to demonstrate now, but with python, namely list comprehension, with-constructs, iterator concept, you're really able to write short and still readable code. I'd guess half the length, and a friction of the amounts of brackets required. PHP is not the language of choice for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so just the rough frame of what to do:

```
from lxml import etree
import csv

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_string, parser=etree.XMLParser())
with open(outfilepath, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(<fieldnames>)
    for item_node in tree.xpath('//item'):
        var1 = item_node.xpath('.../text()')[0]
        ...
        writer.writerow(var1, var2, ...)
```

If your XML is really big and you can't fit it into memory, you have also different options, to read sequentially from a file. Nevertheless, I parsed HTMLs with several MBs that way.